# Yii2 validation rule in model have multiple scenarios

Tags: model, yii2

I have 3 scenarios in the model
in the rules() method and I want to use a rule on 2 scenarios ,

```
[['username', 'email', 'password'], 'required', 'on' => self::SCENARIO_REGISTER]
```

I read the guide , haven't find a way to bind a rule to 2 scenarios at the same time? Is there any way to do that ?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can pass an array to `on`:

```
[['username', 'email', 'password'], 'required', 'on' => [self::SCENARIO_REGISTER, self::SCENARIO_OTHER]]
```